# showing the div element on focus of previous div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**html**

```
<div class="channel">
   <div class="programs" id="p1"></div>
   <div class="selec_pro" id="s1" style="display:none;"></div>
   <div class="programs" id="p2"></div>
   <div class="selec_pro" id="s2" style="display:none;"></div>
   <div class="programs" id="p3"></div>
   <div class="selec_pro" id="s3" style="display:none;"></div>
   <div class="programs" id="p4"></div>
   <div class="selec_pro" id="s4" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

> The div element under class channel are created dynamically. On focus
>   of class programs, selec_pro next to that class program div needs to
>   be display block. After that focus off selec_pro needs to be display
>   none.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Show some effort next time, showing your attempt in question itself and btw posting at least valid HTML markup...

Answer (score 1):

Try this in CSS:

```
.selec_pro {
    display: none;
}

.programs:focus + .selec_pro {
    display: block;
}
```

The `+` is the CSS adjacent sibling selector. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Comment: Good way but still needs to make `div.programs` focusable (tabbable?). Use then `tabindex` attribute   http://jsfiddle.net/636e428e/